# Linked list I got from a tutorial is not working

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I was doing a linked list tutorial and copied a code when I noticed the "remove(self, d)" function doesn't work. After further understanding of that function I'm confused on how it overwrites its pointers.

Why doesn't "remove(self, d)" not work? Is the tutorial code false?

How does the function "remove(self, d)" reference the next node in the list when there isn't any value given to it?

It is supposed to be "next_node" but no value is given to it.

The tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQDxmjfkIKY&list=PLrWyYwpYpIbK1knEciTJqwe_zH5BZV77F&index=2

Time stamp: 1:15:46

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, d, n = None, p = None):
        self.data = d
        self.next_node = n
        self.prev_node = p

    def __str__(self):
        return("(" + str(self.data) + ")")


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self, r = None):
        self.root = r
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, d):
        new_node = Node(d, self.root)
        self.root = new_node
        self.size += 1

    def find(self, d):
        this_node = self.root
        while this_node is not None:
            if this_node.data == d:
                return d
            else:
                this_node = this_node.next_node

    def remove(self, d):
        this_node = self.root
        prev_node = None
 
        while this_node is not None:
            if this_node.data == d:
                if prev_node is not None:
                    prev_node.next_node = this_node.next_node # Changes the current nodes pointer to the previous node. The current node can no longer be accessed. "next.node" is the pointer
                else:
                    self.root = this_node.next_node # Basically the 2nd node in the list is now the root if the first node in the list was the root
                self.size -=1 # decreases size
                return True
            else:
                prev_node = this_node #The loop goes forward in the list by changing the previous node to this node
                this_node = this_node.next_node # By going forward the current node changes to the next node or "this_node" from the previous node gets a new pointer
            return False

    def print_list(self):
        this_node = self.root
        while this_node is not None:
            print(this_node, end = "->")
            this_node = this_node.next_node
        print("none")


myList = LinkedList()
myList.add(5)
myList.add(8)
myList.add(12)
myList.print_list()
print("size = " + str(myList.size))
myList.remove(8)
print("size = " +str(myList.size))
```

Output:

```
(12)->(8)->(5)->none
size = 3
size = 3
```

Comment: _How does the function "remove(self, d)" reference the next node in the list when there isn't any value given to it?_ The data value `d` certainly is provided, and the function searches through the list for a node with that data value.

Comment: Where is "next_node" given a value? It looks like "d" is only used for searching nothing else I may be wrong.

Comment: Should I just follow a different tutorial? I made so much progress already.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the problem, outdent the return statement in the remove function as shown below:

```
def remove(self, d):
    this_node = self.root
    prev_node = None
 
    while this_node is not None:
        if this_node.data == d:
            if prev_node is not None:
                prev_node.next_node = this_node.next_node # Changes the current nodes pointer to the previous node. The current node can no longer be accessed. "next.node" is the pointer
            else:
                self.root = this_node.next_node # Basically the 2nd node in the list is now the root if the first node in the list was the root
            self.size -=1 # decreases size
            return True
        else:
            prev_node = this_node #The loop goes forward in the list by changing the previous node to this node
            this_node = this_node.next_node # By going forward the current node changes to the next node or "this_node" from the previous node gets a new pointer
    return False
```

Comment: It looks the exact same. I copied and pasted your version and the problem isn't solved. Which return statement are you talking about because there are 2?

Comment: The `return False` at the very end should be outdented so it is at the same level as the `while` loop, not inside it.  (This code still has it indented one level too far)

Comment: I just fixed the mistake in my code

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the last statement in `remove` (i.e. `return False`) is inside the `while` block, which means that after the first iteration the function exits. That statement should be executed when the `while` loop has completed, so *outside* of it -- as can also be seen in the video-fragment you referred to:

```
    def remove(self, d):
        this_node = self.root
        prev_node = None
 
        while this_node is not None:
            if this_node.data == d:
                if prev_node is not None:
                    prev_node.next_node = this_node.next_node # Changes the current nodes pointer to the previous node. The current node can no longer be accessed. "next.node" is the pointer
                else:
                    self.root = this_node.next_node
                    self.size -=1
                return True
            else:
                prev_node = this_node
                this_node = this_node.next_node
        return False  #  after while loop has completed
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I'm very grateful. Hate these types of errors.